# With access token get user details using REST API from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

In our APP we have the user token for a user on Azure DevOps.  We use this to perform certain actions in the Azure DevOps instance using REST APIs.  In order to ignore webhooks triggered by actions performed by this particular user, we need to know the user's email.  Is there an API that can provide that?

I tried the `GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/{id}?api-version=5.1` with "`me`" in place of `{id}` as suggested by their documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 but it throws "**Resource cannot be found**" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we need to know the user's email. Is there an API that can provide
>   that?

For this issue , you can use [Users - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api to achieve this .

Sample Request:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Sample Response:

```
{
      "subjectKind": "user",
      "metaType": "member",
      "domain": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
      "principalName": "TeamFoundationService (TEAM FOUNDATION)",
      "mailAddress": "xxx.@xxx.com",
      "origin": "vsts",
      "originId": "00ca946b-2fe9-4f2a-ae2f-40d5c48001bc",
      "displayName": "TeamFoundationService (TEAM FOUNDATION)",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Fabrikam/_apis/Graph/Users/acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"
        },
        "memberships": {
          "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Fabrikam/_apis/Graph/Memberships/acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"
        },
        "membershipState": {
          "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Fabrikam/_apis/Graph/MembershipStates/acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"
        },
        "storageKey": {
          "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Fabrikam/_apis/Graph/StorageKeys/acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"
        },
        "avatar": {
          "href": "https://dev.azure.com/Fabrikam/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Fabrikam/_apis/Graph/Users/acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj",
      "descriptor": "acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"
    }
```

You can get the user's email from the **mailAddress** variable in the response body.By specifying the **descriptor** parameter in the [Users-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api, you can get the details of a specific user.

Comment: Thank you.  I also figured out that I can use the profile API to get the email too.

Answer (score 0):

The post is quite a time ago, but maybe my answer will help some other peoples. The docs are a bit confusing here. This url can be used:

[https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/_apis/profile/profiles/me](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization%7D%7D/_apis/profile/profiles/me)

I tested it successfully with a PAT (Secret of Basic Auth, Username empty).